# Gnuplot does not write local name of days in Windows

Tags: datetime, gnuplot, locale

I want Gnuplot to use the norwegian name of the days (%a) as xtics. In Linux I can be done by using`set locale 'nb_NO.utf-8'`.
But in Windows 10, when trying`set locale 'Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252'`, this results in the error`Locale not available`.
The output of `show locale` is:

```
gnuplot LC_CTYPE   Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252
gnuplot encoding   utf8
gnuplot LC_TIME    Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.1252
gnuplot LC_NUMERIC C
```

I suppose the error is due to the character **å** (unocode 00E5, Latin Small Letter A with ring). How can I set correct locale in Gnuplot when using Windows?

Comment: Did you try `'nb'`?

Comment: ```'set locale nb'``` does not work , neither  ```'set locale nb.utf-8'```  nor  ```'set locale nb.1252'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I get with the following code. Tested with gnuplot 5.4 under Win10. I hope it will solve your problem.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0 and if you change `(i+4)` to `(i+2)` for gnuplot4.6.x)

```
### set locale to different languages, print weekdays
reset session

myLocales = "English French German Norwegian Icelandic"

do for [myLocale in myLocales] {
    set locale myLocale
    print sprintf("\n### %s:",myLocale)
    do for [i=0:6] { print strftime("%A",3600*24*(i+4)) }
}

### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
### English:
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday

### French:
lundi
mardi
mercredi
jeudi
vendredi
samedi
dimanche

### German:
Montag
Dienstag
Mittwoch
Donnerstag
Freitag
Samstag
Sonntag

### Norwegian:
mandag
tirsdag
onsdag
torsdag
fredag
lørdag
søndag

### Icelandic:
mánudagur
þriðjudagur
miðvikudagur
fimmtudagur
föstudagur
laugardagur
sunnudagur
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you!